# Android Virtual KeyboardListener

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` which when some text entered the virtual keyboard appears and when I press enter I can't get focus in my second `EditText`, but some times it works.

Anybody please help.

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)// key code for virtual keyboard next
            {
                System.out.println("Event catched>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                edittext.requestFocus();

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that from your code.

You need to setup the [android:imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) correctly in your `EditText`.

Answer (score 2):

Used `android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"` on the Edittext